# How to install openCV on WSL + UBUNTU20.04 + python3.8 using Anaconda?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ubuntu-20.04

I am trying to install openCV on WSL+UBUNTU20.04 with python3.8. I am trying to install using miniconda without any success.

After searching over internet, it seems that openCV may not be supported on python3.8. If anyone has done this successfully, I would appreciate some help.

Update: Solved. Please check my answer.

Comment: opencv and python 3.8 work just fine together. please give a source for your claim.

Comment: I would recommend staying away from anaconda/conda. their packages are a mess. use pip, python's own package manager interface. the [`opencv-python` package](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/) works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Christoph's suggestion, I decided to install using pip in the virtual enviornment of conda. I did the following:

1. Run
   conda create -n env_name
   source activate env_name
   , where env_name is the name of your virtual environment.
2. To install pip to my venv directory, I ran:
   conda install pip
3. I went to the actual venv folder in anaconda directory. It should be somewhere like:
   /home/$USER/miniconda3/envs/env_name/
4. I then installed new packages by doing
   /home/$USER/miniconda3/envs/env_name/bin/pip install opencv-python